# Why can't I do consumer setValueDeserializer on spring kafka using kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, deserialization, spring-kafka, consumer

When trying to implement DefaultKafkaConsumerFactoryCustomizer in kotlin Spring Kafka, the parameter in the setValueDeserializer method is nothing and cannot be customized.[image]

method in DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory
[image]

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.8.22'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.8.22'
```

So I can't override it, so I defined it in properties.

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=CREATE:com.example.demo.BundleView$CreateBundleViewImpl
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

but kafka message

However, when kafka message enters the snake case, SerializationException: Can't deserialize data error occurs.
It works normally if it is used as a camel case.

Comment: I am not a Kotlin expert, but you probably have to specify a concrete type for the factory, instead of `*`. When the serializer is instantiated by Kafka (via the properties) it cannot use Boot's `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your answer. As you said, I was able to do setvaluedeserializer if I cast the type.
There was also a way to inject the custom deserializer because the objectMapper of the boot could not be written when injected through the properties.

Another option was to customize the messageConverter by writing the stringDeserializer.

Thank you for your answer!